# Set-Cookie requests

Tags: python, python-requests, setcookie, python-requests-html

I have the response headers from which I want to get a Set-cookies(photos[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry8DR.png)).
However when I take them out I get this:{..., **'Set-Cookie': 'yandexuid=419738311669894372; Max-Age=315360000; Domain=.yandex.ru; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 28 Nov 2032 11:32:52 GMT; Secure, uniqueuid=377310871669894372; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 28 Nov 2032 11:32:52 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax', 'ETag': 'W/"2cd4-f4fDDczFbxRErDt3R3QH72yfxjk"', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'**}
How can this be fixed? I will clarify that I need to get the Session_id from the Set-Cookie.

Requests headers(photo)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73h6Z.png)
My code:

```
url = 'https://passport.yandex.ru/registration-validations/change-pwd-commit'

header = {
    'User-Agent': my_user_agent,
    'referer': 'https://passport.yandex.ru/',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Host': 'passport.yandex.ru',
    'Origin': 'https://passport.yandex.ru',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

data = {
    'csrf_token': csrf_token,
    'track_id': track_id
}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=header, data=data)
cookie = response.headers
print(cookie)
```

Comment: I will clarify that I need to get the Session_id from the Set-Cookie

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. What output do you want?

Comment: @luk2302 i want to get session_id from set-cookie